# meaning of the phrase "the why and the how of something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [TED talks](https://youtu.be/Wgt8QUHQjw8). It is at 1 minute and 59 second. Here is the context:

> We are begining to glimpse **the why and the how of** beauty, at least in terms of what it means for the human face and form.

Could you please rephrase the sentece for me?

Comment: The **whys** of something are the reasons for its existence, for its being what it is. The **hows** of something refer to its manner or mode of being, the way in which it acts or behaves.  Nominalizing these question-words is an informal way of speaking.

Comment: A combination of "We are beginning to (get a) glimpse at why beauty is important..." and "We are beginning to (get a) glimpse at how beauty is perceived..." *get a glimpse* would be far more natural.